# Creating Custom Legend without using Legend class for Line chart in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts

I am trying to create legend in a customized manner(Hbox,Vbox containing image to indicate marker shape of line series chart) , since am creating customised legend am unable to include the shape of the marker of Line series in the legend set.The following is my code sample:

```
var img:Image = new Image();
img.source= new ClassFactory( mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer);
```

its not at all displaying an image.
Is it good to use image or iflexdisplayobject

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the source code of `LegendItem` where you can see that the ItemRenderer instance is assigned to a `IFlexDisplayObject` (the marker).

Just look at the `updateDisplayList` method of LegendItem to understand how to handle the renderers.